# iCloud Sync with Core Data SQLite Stability

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, icloud, reliability

Good day everyone,

I am designing an inventory application using Core Data UIManagedDocument model and at the point of providing a data back up design. I am considering iCloud but have read online about chronic problems with iCloud and reliability with SQLlite.

Before I head down this path have people had good experience using the model? Is it stable enough for a production application? I need for IOS 5 and above.

Many thanks
-Jim

Comment: Just be aware that using iCloud Core Data sync is not a backup strategy, it is intended for synchronising data between devices.  Storing the document in the local /Documents directory will ensure the files get backed up using iTunes or iCloud backups, depending on the users selection.

Comment: Good point. I will use both strategies. Thanks Duncan

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQLite is very stable. I think it is stable more than other databases. 
1. SQLite not uses Server Client principle. It will avoid speed and package lost.
2  SQLite is reading from File system and special lock mechanism over FS.
3. SQLite something directly read from file system with C programming language. So no lose time handle other thing which is BIG db is doing.

it is depend your project. Because SQLite has some limitation also. locking, table rename or something else. you can refer below link and make sure does your project requirement matching or not.

https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html